# How to pass ObservableInt between Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, observable, android-databinding

I have an `ObservableInt` in Activity1, and want to pass it through intent to Activity2. But no matter how I pass the it, the `OnPropertyChangedCallback`s bound to the `ObservableInt` are lost. How to prevent the lost?

```
// Activity1
private ObservableInt var = new ObservableInt(0);
var.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback1);
public void goToActivity2(View view) {
    var.set(1); // fires callback1
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Activity2.class);
    // first way to pass ObservableInt
    intent.putExtra("VAR", (Parcelable) var);
    // second way to pass ObservableInt
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("VAR", var);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
// Activity2
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ObservableInt a = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("VAR");
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ObservableInt b = bundle.getParcelable("VAR");
    a.set(2); // cannot fire callback1
    b.set(3); // cannot fire callback1
}
```

---

```
//Activity1
private ObservableInt var = new Observable(0);
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    var.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback1);
    var.set(1); // fires callback1
    Fragment1 frag = Fragment1.newInstance(var); // instantiates Fragment1
    // inflate some layout with frag
}

public void goToActivity2 (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, goToActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("VAR", var);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Fragment1
public static Fragment1 newInstance(ObservableInt var) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("VAR", var);
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ObservableInt var = (ObservableInt) getArguments().getSerializable("VAR");
    var.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback2);
    var.set(2); // fires callback1 and callback2
}

//Activity2
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ObservableInt var= (ObservableInt) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("VAR");
    var.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback3);
    var.set(3); // only fires callback3 :(
}
```

Comment: Such a bad idea. Why don't you use event bus?

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to event bus. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @ProkashSarkar The event bus paradigm is (somewhat controversially) considered obsolete.  One of the most popular event buses, Otto, has been abandoned by its creators in favor of Reactive Streams.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thanks for making it clear. I wasn't suggesting to use Otto or something like that. We can also create event bus style approach with RxJava. Checkout my posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a `Parcelable`, the object that comes out the other side is not the same instance.

Per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableInt.html):

> This class is parcelable and serializable but callbacks are ignored when the object is parcelled / serialized.

Comment: But when I pass the `ObservableInt` from Activity to Fragment, the callbacks are still working. Why? The Code example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534557/passing-observableint-between-activities-the-onpropertychangedcallbacks-are-los)

Comment: @Moon this is because you are using the same instance object (no parceling/unparceling is done)

Comment: @pskink I thought there was serializing/deserializing from function `newInstance` to `onCreateView`. Am I wrong?

Comment: extend your `ObservableInt` and override `writeToParcel` method calling `super.writeToParcel` and some `Log.d` and you will see when your class is parceled

Comment: @Moon That's what I'd expect to happen.  I'm actually more inclined to suspect that when you pass the `ObservableInt` to the fragment, `callback1` is either not being called when you think, or being called but not for the reason you think.  Hard to say without seeing more code.  Can you create a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the Observable via Intent, use Event bus style with RxJava:

```
public class RxEventBus {

    private static RxEventBus instance;

    private PublishSubject<Observable> observable_bus = PublishSubject.create();

    public static RxEventBus getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RxEventBus();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void sendBusObservable(Observable observable_bus) {
        observable_bus.onNext(observable_bus);
    }

    public Observable<Observable> getBusObject() {
        return observable_bus;
    }
  }
```

To pass an Observable From **Activity1**,

```
private ObservableInt var = new ObservableInt(0);
var.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback1);

RxEventBus.getInstance().sendBusObservable(var);
```

From **Activity2** Subscribe for the data changes,

```
 RxEventBus rxEventBus = RxEventBus.getInstance();
        rxEventBus.getBusObject()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(a -> {
                    if (a instanceof Observable) {
                        Observable observable = (Observable) a;
                        // do the rest with received observable
                    }
                });
```